# Spring how to manage a mapping table (Many to Many)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am developing an app where the user can have one or more roles, for this I decided to created a mapping (intermediate) table, so I ended with `User`, `Role` and `UserRole` like this:

[image: Mapping Table]

In this app the role(s) a user has determines wheneaver he can access certain views or actions in the frontend. The only thing I need is to retrive the roles a user has and add/delete them. JPA Tools created he following EJB for me (simplified):

**USER**

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the usuario database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Usuario.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Usuario u")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int idUsuario;

    private List<RolUsuario> rolUsuarios;

    public Usuario() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getIdUsuario() {
        return this.idUsuario;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(int idUsuario) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to RolUsuario
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="usuario")
    public List<RolUsuario> getRolUsuarios() {
        return this.rolUsuarios;
    }

    public void setRolUsuarios(List<RolUsuario> rolUsuarios) {
        this.rolUsuarios = rolUsuarios;
    }

    public RolUsuario addRolUsuario(RolUsuario rolUsuario) {
        getRolUsuarios().add(rolUsuario);
        rolUsuario.setUsuario(this);

        return rolUsuario;
    }

    public RolUsuario removeRolUsuario(RolUsuario rolUsuario) {
        getRolUsuarios().remove(rolUsuario);
        rolUsuario.setUsuario(null);

        return rolUsuario;
    }

}
```

**USER_ROLE**

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the rol_usuario database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="rol_usuario")
@NamedQuery(name="RolUsuario.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM RolUsuario r")
public class RolUsuario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idRol_Usuario;
    private Usuario usuario;
    private Rol rol;

    public RolUsuario() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getIdRol_Usuario() {
        return this.idRol_Usuario;
    }

    public void setIdRol_Usuario(int idRol_Usuario) {
        this.idRol_Usuario = idRol_Usuario;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Usuario
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return this.usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Rol
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public Rol getRol() {
        return this.rol;
    }

    public void setRol(Rol rol) {
        this.rol = rol;
    }

}
```

In my project I am using the EJB to create POJO for the frontend. When I ask for the full list of roles for a given user how should I go about doing this:

1. Create a UserRole repository using CrudRepository with a metod like
   `List<RolUsuario> findByUsuario(Usuario user);`
2. Return the list of `UserRole` to my `User Service` and go over the
   the list extracting each Role into a `UserPOJO`
3. Send to frontend.

Or is there any way to just get right off the bat a list of `Roles` in table `UserRole` where `User`(Id?) = something?

This is hard to describe for me. My app only cares for the roles of a user, not the mapping table entity, so the botton line is that somehow I have to get them but I don't know where to start.

Any pointers would be extremely useful.

Edit:

Or I could...

1. Create UserRole for new role addition to a user.
2. Adding UserRole to the List inside User.
3. To get the roles of a user get the UserRolelist instead.

Comment: One option is to not have UserRole model but only having User and Role. You can specify is User to have list of Roles and in Role table to have list of users.

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: The problem is that the intermediate table may become a entity on its own some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema for User and Role is not commonly used. I advice to you make a `@ManyToMany` association from a user to roles. If you will need to map a join table to the entity (unlikely) you can do it later. And, please, use English identifiers and Java naming convention (`idRol_Usuario`). It will help you and others.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long pid;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Role> roles;

}

@Entity
@Table
public class Role {

    @Id
    private Long pid;

    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

You can use `Set<Role>` too

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Comment: Yeah sorry about the names, I'm studying in a Hispanic country so I sometimes forget to switch them. It is very late so I'll try this tomorrow, just one question; Does using this means getting rid of the intermediate table? Like going to sqlWorkbench and deleting said table and adding a new many to many relationship?

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper No. Hibernate will create a join table for `many-to-many` relation. You can specify it name and column names using a `@JoinTable` annotation.

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper you can refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35790542/3405171) for a `@JoinTable` example. But, maybe, you don't need to use such complex stuff (don't need to specify names of constraints).

Answer (score 1):

The roles of a `User` and in the `rolUsuarios` list. In your `User` service, look up a user, often with the `id`. If you have the `idUsuario`, then user `EntityManger.find(Usuario.class, idUsuario)` and you can read the user roles by `getRolUsuarios`, or at least that would be the typical way to do it.

In your table design you have a `id` for the user_role table (iduserrole), which is not typical for a `join table`. Typically, you just create your entity with a `OneToMany` annotation and the `join table` is created for you:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    Set<Role> roles;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

}
```

These two classes would create three tables, the `User` table, the `Role` table, and the `User_Role` `Join Table`. The join table would have the each id from the user and the role tables in it, and nothing more.

EDIT: The `roles` is changed to `ManyToMany` because otherwise a constraint will be added to the database that will prevent the a `Role` from being added to more than one user. Typically the role table has only unique roles in it, e.g., `USER`, `ADMIN`, etc., and so you want to be able to assign them to more than one user.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Looks like `User` and `Role` should to have a `many-to-many` relation.

Comment: `many-to-many` means that  two users can have `ADMIN` role, for an example. It doesn't contradict a fact that _typically the role table has only unique roles_.

Comment: Yea, you're right. I was thinking of ManyToOne before I had my coffee. Thanks again.