# ADD CONSTRAINT in Hibernate tutorial

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

This example comes from the JBOSS's hibernate tutorial. The link is there:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables.

Example 79. Unidirectional @OneToMany association

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
public static class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    public Person() {
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }
}

@Entity(name = "Phone")
public static class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String number;

    public Phone() {
    }

    public Phone(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
CREATE TABLE Person (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)

CREATE TABLE Person_Phone (
    Person_id BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    phones_id BIGINT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Phone (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    number VARCHAR(255) ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)

ALTER TABLE Person_Phone
ADD CONSTRAINT UK_9uhc5itwc9h5gcng944pcaslf
UNIQUE (phones_id)

ALTER TABLE Person_Phone
ADD CONSTRAINT FKr38us2n8g5p9rj0b494sd3391
FOREIGN KEY (phones_id) REFERENCES Phone

ALTER TABLE Person_Phone
ADD CONSTRAINT FK2ex4e4p7w1cj310kg2woisjl2
FOREIGN KEY (Person_id) REFERENCES Person
```

My question is, in this example:

1) Why does the ADD CONSTRAINT looks like a machine generated string, "FKr38us2n8g5p9rj0b494sd3391"? Shouldn't it be created manually with a more meaningful constraint?

2) Is the ADD CONSTRAINT optional in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the ADD CONSTRAINT looks like a machine generated string,
>   "FKr38us2n8g5p9rj0b494sd3391"? Shouldn't it be created manually with a
>   more meaningful constraint?

The constraint is not generated by a database, of course. It is generated by Hibernate.

This strange name `FKr38us2n8g5p9rj0b494sd3391` is generated, because of a constraint names length restriction in some databases. For an example, in Oracle database, it can't be more than 30 symbols length.

Hibernate generates a constraint name by concatenating tables and property names and convert the result to `MD5`, producing strings like `FKr38us2n8g5p9rj0b494sd3391`. This code snippet from Hibernate source

```
/**
 * Hash a constraint name using MD5. Convert the MD5 digest to base 35
 * (full alphanumeric), guaranteeing
 * that the length of the name will always be smaller than the 30
 * character identifier restriction enforced by a few dialects.
 *
 * @param s The name to be hashed.
 *
 * @return String The hashed name.
 */
public String hashedName(String s) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );
        md.reset();
        md.update( s.getBytes() );
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger( 1, digest );
        // By converting to base 35 (full alphanumeric), we guarantee
        // that the length of the name will always be smaller than the 30
        // character identifier restriction enforced by a few dialects.
        return bigInt.toString( 35 );
    }
    catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException e ) {
        throw new HibernateException( "Unable to generate a hashed name!", e );
    }
}
```

You can generate your own constraint names (unique and foreign key) using `ImplicitNamingStrategy`. You can refer [Hibernate5NamingStrategy](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/cfg/strategy/hibernate5/Hibernate5NamingStrategy.java) , as an example.

Also to specify constraint names (in common case) you can use the `@ForeignKey` and `@JoinColumn` annotations.

In the case of a join table you can use a `@JoinTable` annotation, as @uditkhare suggested. But you need to provide much more information (it is not very convenient)

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name="person_phones", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "f_person_pid", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
            name = "fk_person_phones_person")), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_phone",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_person_phones_phone")),
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uk_person_phones_phone",
            columnNames = { "fk_phone" }))
private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
```

> Is the ADD CONSTRAINT optional in this case?

No. It is not optional. It is need to model a `@OneToMany` relation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is generated by hibernate only.

If you want to define those by yourself, you can use something as below:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(name="my_unique_key", columnNames={"phones_id"}))
```

Comment: You mean the 3 'create table' statements are made by developers, but the "Alter table" is added by DB. So in the tutorial, I only need the two classes definition and the table creation, without needing to worry about the 'alter table', if I want to try out the tutorial. Right?

Comment: @user697911 All schema creation scripts are generated by Hibernate, not by a database. See my answer.

Comment: @user697911 - create table statements are also generated by hibernate.

u just need to create model classes(or mapping xml if useing xml approach), all ddl will be generated by hibernate as per the "hbm2ddl" property

Comment: @uditkhare You should provide much more information in @JoinTable. For an example, I am not sure that Hibernate generates `phones_id` column name. And `my_unique_key` should be an unique name in the tablespace, of course.

Comment: @v.ladynev yes I have just given a basic idea above. It should be something like - @JoinTable(name = "Person_Phone" , 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Person_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name ="phones_id",  referencedColumnName = "id") },
  uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(name="my_unique_key", columnNames={"phones_id"}) )

Comment: @uditkhare Yes. Something like that. I provided a full example in my answer with foreign constraint names too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105360/discussion-between-udit-khare-and-v-ladynev).